# Add div's ID to url after click and then remove this from url after clicking close btn

Tags: javascript, html

I have done part with adding div's ID to the url but I have trouble with then deleting it after clicking close button inside this `speaker--card` div with class `speakers--overlay-close`.

```
    var myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers--card');
    var closeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers--overlay-close');

    for(var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
        myDivs[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
          console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
          let thisID = this.getAttribute("id");
          window.location.href = window.location.href + "#" + thisID;
        });
    }
```

I have tested some split functions etc. but it is not working and url stays the same - with the `#` + `id`.

Comment: to be honest there is not much need to do this via JS. Use normal Links to handle adding this parameters. If user click back button on their browser the `#` is gone automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the close button is inside the div, when you click on it the event propagates and runs the click event handler for div which again adds the hash value. You can stop the event propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()` in close button event handler and then remove the hash from url.

```js
var myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers--card');
var closeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers--overlay-close');

for (var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
  myDivs[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let thisID = this.getAttribute("id");
    window.location.hash = thisID;
  });

  closeDiv[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location.hash = '';
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have posted my solution above but maybe yours is better.

Comment: In your solution you are setting `window.location.href` directly. This might create problem if user is able to click on div multiple times because it will keep appending `#id` to the end of url on every click.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this finally but not sure if it is the right way:

```
var myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers--card');
var closeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers--overlay-close');

for(var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
    myDivs[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      let thisID = this.getAttribute("id");
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "#" + thisID;
    });
}
for(var i = 0; i < closeDivs.length; i++) {
    var closeDiv = closeDivs[i];
    closeDiv.onclick = function() {
      var newURL = location.href.split("#")[0];
      window.history.pushState('object', document.title, newURL);
    }
}
```